# Issue in conflict in stash

Tags: java, jgit, git-stash

This is my scenario

1. I did change on file a.
2. I created new file b
3. do stash
4. do change in file a.
5. do commit
6. do use stash
7. call to get status -> get only one file in conflit but I didn't get the file untracked b.

It is occured only in this scenario without the conflict it is working ok

I am using jgit org.eclipse.jgit,3.4.2.201412180340-r

code for stash

```
@Override
protected boolean handlePost(RequestInfo requestInfo) throws ServletException {

JSONObject requestPayload = requestInfo.getJSONRequest();
HttpServletRequest request = requestInfo.request;
HttpServletResponse response = requestInfo.response;
Repository db = requestInfo.db;

String indexMessage = requestPayload.optString(GitConstants.KEY_STASH_INDEX_MESSAGE);
String workingDirectoryMessage = requestPayload.optString(GitConstants.KEY_STASH_WORKING_DIRECTORY_MESSAGE);
boolean includeUntracked = requestPayload.optBoolean(GitConstants.KEY_STASH_INCLUDE_UNTRACKED, false);

try {

    Git git = new Git(db);
    StashCreateCommand stashCreate = git.stashCreate();
    stashCreate.setPerson(new PersonIdent(db));
    stashCreate.setIncludeUntracked(includeUntracked);

    if (!indexMessage.isEmpty())
        stashCreate.setIndexMessage(indexMessage);

    if (!workingDirectoryMessage.isEmpty())
        stashCreate.setWorkingDirectoryMessage(workingDirectoryMessage);

    stashCreate.call();
    return true;

} catch (Exception ex) {
    String msg = "An error occured for stash command.";
    return statusHandler.handleRequest(request, response, new ServerStatus(IStatus.ERROR, HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, msg, ex));
}
```

}

code for use stash

```
@Override
    protected boolean handlePut(RequestInfo requestInfo) throws ServletException {

        JSONObject requestPayload = requestInfo.getJSONRequest();
        HttpServletRequest request = requestInfo.request;
        HttpServletResponse response = requestInfo.response;
        Repository db = requestInfo.db;

        /* gitapi/stash/<stashRev>/file/(...) */
        String stashRev = requestInfo.gitSegment;

        boolean applyIndex = requestPayload.optBoolean(GitConstants.KEY_STASH_APPLY_INDEX, true);
        boolean applyUntracked = requestPayload.optBoolean(GitConstants.KEY_STASH_APPLY_UNTRACKED, true);

        try {

            Git git = new Git(db);

            /* check for empty stash */
            if (isStashEmpty(git)) {
                String msg = "Failed to apply stashed changes due to an empty stash.";
                return statusHandler.handleRequest(request, response, new ServerStatus(IStatus.WARNING, HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, msg, null));
            }

            StashApplyCommand applyCommand = new StashApplyCommand(db);

            if (stashRev != null) {

                StashRef stashRef = getStashRef(git, stashRev);
                if (stashRef == null) {
                    String msg = NLS.bind("Invalid stash reference {0}.", stashRev);
                    return statusHandler.handleRequest(request, response, new ServerStatus(IStatus.ERROR, HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, msg, null));
                }

                applyCommand.setStashRef(stashRef.getStringRef());
                applyCommand.setApplyUntracked(applyUntracked);
                applyCommand.setApplyIndex(applyIndex);
                applyCommand.call();

            } else {

                /* git stash pop */
                applyCommand.setApplyUntracked(applyUntracked);
                applyCommand.setApplyIndex(applyIndex);
                applyCommand.call();
                StashDropCommand dropCommand = git.stashDrop();
                dropCommand.setAll(false);
                dropCommand.call();

            }

            return true;

        } catch (GitAPIException gitEx) {
            String msg = "An error occured for stash command issue with conflict.";
            return statusHandler.handleRequest(request, response, new ServerStatus(IStatus.WARNING, HttpServletResponse.SC_CONFLICT, msg, gitEx));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            String msg = "An error occured for stash command.";
            return statusHandler.handleRequest(request, response, new ServerStatus(IStatus.ERROR, HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, msg, ex));
        }
    }
```

code for commit

```
@Override
protected boolean handlePost(RequestInfo requestInfo) throws ServletException {
    String gitSegment = requestInfo.gitSegment;
    HttpServletRequest request = requestInfo.request;
    HttpServletResponse response = requestInfo.response;
    Repository db = requestInfo.db;
    String pattern = requestInfo.relativePath;
    JSONObject requestObject = requestInfo.getJSONRequest();
    try {
        String commitToMerge = requestObject.optString(GitConstants.KEY_MERGE, null);
        if (commitToMerge != null) {
            boolean squash = requestObject.optBoolean(GitConstants.KEY_SQUASH, false);
            return merge(request, response, db, commitToMerge, squash);
        }

        String commitToRebase = requestObject.optString(GitConstants.KEY_REBASE, null);
        String rebaseOperation = requestObject.optString(GitConstants.KEY_OPERATION, null);
        if (commitToRebase != null) {
            return rebase(request, response, db, commitToRebase, rebaseOperation);
        }

        String commitToCherryPick = requestObject.optString(GitConstants.KEY_CHERRY_PICK, null);
        if (commitToCherryPick != null) {
            return cherryPick(request, response, db, commitToCherryPick);
        }

        String commitToRevert = requestObject.optString(GitConstants.KEY_REVERT, null);
        if (commitToRevert != null) {
            return revert(request, response, db, commitToRevert);
        }

        String newCommit = requestObject.optString(GitConstants.KEY_COMMIT_NEW, null);
        if (newCommit != null)
            return identifyNewCommitResource(request, response, db, newCommit);

        String reviewReqLogin = requestObject.optString(GitConstants.KEY_REVIEW_REQ_NOTIFY_LOGIN);
        if (reviewReqLogin != null && reviewReqLogin.length() != 0) {
            String reviewReqUrl = requestObject.optString(GitConstants.KEY_REVIEW_REQ_URL);
            String ReviewReqCommit = requestObject.optString(GitConstants.KEY_REVIEW_REQ_COMMIT);
            String ReviewReqAuthorName = requestObject.optString(GitConstants.KEY_REVIEW_REQ_AUTHOR_NAME);
            String ReviewMessage = requestObject.optString(GitConstants.KEY_REVIEW_REQ_MESSAGE);
            return sendNotification(request, response, db, reviewReqLogin, ReviewReqCommit, reviewReqUrl, ReviewReqAuthorName, ReviewMessage);
        }

        ObjectId refId = db.resolve(gitSegment);
        if (refId == null || !Constants.HEAD.equals(gitSegment)) {
            String msg = NLS.bind("Commit failed. Ref must be HEAD and is {0}", gitSegment);
            return statusHandler.handleRequest(request, response, new ServerStatus(IStatus.ERROR, HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, msg, null));
        }

        String message = requestObject.optString(GitConstants.KEY_COMMIT_MESSAGE, null);
        if (message == null || message.isEmpty()) {
            return statusHandler.handleRequest(request, response, new ServerStatus(IStatus.ERROR, HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST,
                    "Missing commit message.", null));
        }

        Git git = new Git(db);
        CommitCommand cc = git.commit();
        Config config = git.getRepository().getConfig();

        boolean amend = Boolean.parseBoolean(requestObject.optString(GitConstants.KEY_COMMIT_AMEND, null));
        boolean insertChangeId = config.getBoolean(ConfigConstants.CONFIG_GERRIT_SECTION, ConfigConstants.CONFIG_KEY_CREATECHANGEID, false)
                || Boolean.parseBoolean(requestObject.optString(GitConstants.KEY_CHANGE_ID, null));

        String committerName = requestObject.optString(GitConstants.KEY_COMMITTER_NAME, null);
        String committerEmail = requestObject.optString(GitConstants.KEY_COMMITTER_EMAIL, null);
        String authorName = requestObject.optString(GitConstants.KEY_AUTHOR_NAME, null);
        String authorEmail = requestObject.optString(GitConstants.KEY_AUTHOR_EMAIL, null);

        // workaround of a bug in JGit which causes invalid
        // support of null values of author/committer name/email, see bug
        // 352984
        PersonIdent defPersonIdent = new PersonIdent(db);
        if (committerName == null)
            committerName = defPersonIdent.getName();
        if (committerEmail == null)
            committerEmail = defPersonIdent.getEmailAddress();
        if (authorName == null)
            authorName = committerName;
        if (authorEmail == null)
            authorEmail = committerEmail;
        cc.setCommitter(committerName, committerEmail);
        cc.setAuthor(authorName, authorEmail);
        if (insertChangeId)
            cc.setInsertChangeId(true);

        // support for committing by path: "git commit -o path"
        if (!pattern.isEmpty()) {
            cc.setOnly(pattern);
        }

        try {
            // "git commit [--amend] -m '{message}' [-a|{path}]"
            RevCommit lastCommit = cc.setAmend(amend).setMessage(message).call();

            URI cloneLocation = BaseToCloneConverter.getCloneLocation(getURI(request), BaseToCloneConverter.COMMIT_REFRANGE);
            Commit commit = new Commit(cloneLocation, db, lastCommit, pattern);
            JSONObject result = commit.toJSON();
            OrionServlet.writeJSONResponse(request, response, result, JsonURIUnqualificationStrategy.ALL_NO_GIT);
            return true;
        } catch (GitAPIException e) {
            return statusHandler.handleRequest(request, response, new ServerStatus(IStatus.ERROR, HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST,
                    "An error occurred when committing.", e));
        } catch (UnmergedPathException e) {
            return statusHandler.handleRequest(request, response, new ServerStatus(IStatus.ERROR, HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                    "An internal error occurred when committing.", e));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return statusHandler.handleRequest(request, response, new ServerStatus(IStatus.ERROR, HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                "An error occurred when requesting commit information.", e));
    }
}

code for get status
    @Override
    protected boolean handleGet(RequestInfo requestInfo) throws ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = requestInfo.request;
        HttpServletResponse response = requestInfo.response;
        Repository db = requestInfo.db;

        int page = request.getParameter("page") != null ? new Integer(request.getParameter("page")).intValue() : 1; //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
        int pageSize = request.getParameter("pageSize") != null ? new Integer(request.getParameter("pageSize")).intValue() : PAGE_SIZE; //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
        String messageFilter = request.getParameter("filter"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        try {

            URI baseLocation = getURI(request);
            URI cloneLocation = BaseToCloneConverter.getCloneLocation(baseLocation, BaseToCloneConverter.COMMIT);

            Git git = new Git(db);
            StashListCommand stashList = git.stashList();
            Collection<RevCommit> stashedRefsCollection = stashList.call();

            StashPage stashPage = new StashPage(cloneLocation, db, stashedRefsCollection, page, pageSize, messageFilter);
            OrionServlet.writeJSONResponse(request, response, stashPage.toJSON());
            return true;

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            String msg = "An error occured for stash command.";
            return statusHandler.handleRequest(request, response, new ServerStatus(IStatus.ERROR, HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, msg, ex));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a self-contained code snippet that executes the steps 1. - 7. that you describe? You may also want to use the latest version of JGit (4.5) to avoid running into an old bug.

Comment: It is hard to do so I copy the rest API that I do. Do you know if there was a bug on this scenario ? do I havew any gui to check jgit to see if this issue is a bug ?

Comment: Well, if it's hard, then try hard. Besides, what do the REST API calls have to do with the _scenario_ outlined above? Regarding the ' GUI' you may want to use [Eclipse EGit] to execute the steps, it uses JGit to access Git repositories and therefore reveal if there is a bug in JGit or not.

Comment: It occurred also in eclipse

Comment: What exactly occurred also in Eclipse? Which files did you stash (pt. 3)? Which file(s) had conflicts (pt. 7). If you think this is a bug, you may want to [file a bug](https://eclipse.org/jgit/support/) aginst Eclipse EGit and/or JGit, however, a verifiable self-contained example will be required as well to draw the maintainers attention to it.

Comment: i did the same example modify file and added new file then I call stash. Did a cahane in the same file commit and call stash apply. I got the file that i changed in conflct mide but i didnt get back the new file that i created

Comment: Did you try to explicitly add the untracked file with JGit's `AddCommand` before stashing?

Comment: no i just create the file without stage it and then I did the stash

Comment: As far as I am concerned, I am afraid, you lost me. Can you rework your question to precisely describe the steps that you made, the expected outcome and the actual outcome. That, along with a [self-contained example](http://sscce.org/) would help to answer your question.